# Shift key ignored in C-x Shift-o?

Tags: key-bindings

I wanted to define a key binding `C-x O` (similar to `C-x o` but with a capital `O`). Before doing that, I tried it to see if it is already used. But it seems that <kbd>Shift</kbd>-o is just treated as `o` without holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd>. The echo line shows `C-x o` instead.

I have used key combinations of <kbd>Shift</kbd> with other modifiers, e.g. `M-<` goes to the beginning of buffer but `M-,` doesn't.

*But when used alone, is <kbd>Shift</kbd> always ignored as in `C-x S-o`?*

Also, this makes me wonder:

*Is <kbd>Shift</kbd> key a modifier just as <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>?*; or is it not a modifier, but rather just used to change the character that follows, e.g. from `,` to `<` and `o` to `O`?

Also, I looked up the key `C-x S-o` with `C-h k` and got:

> C-x o (**translated from C-x O**) runs the command other-window ...

> It is bound to C-x o.

It did say, "translated from C-x O". Does this translation always happen? Would it be wrong if I go against it and define `C-x S-o` to do something else?

(This is with Emacs 28 in Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is Shift key a modifier just as Control and Meta?; or is it not a modifier, but rather just used to change the character that follows, e.g. from , to < and o to O?

AFAIK it is both: pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>o</kbd> will cause Emacs to see <kbd>O</kbd> with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier bit  set.

> It did say, "translated from C-x O". Does this translation always happen?

This behavior is controlled by the variable `translate-upper-case-bindings`.

> Would it be wrong if I go against it and define C-x S-o to do something else?

No, you wouldn’t be wrong, as the translation happens only if the lowercase binding exists but the uppercase one doesn’t.  See `C-h v translate-upper-case-bindings RET` for more details.